# WPF, finding control inside itemtemplates datatemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, itemtemplate

How do I programmatically find a control inside an `ItemTemplate`'s `DataTemplate`, e.g. how do I find the `CheckBox` inside the following code:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox x:Name="KontoFeltCheckBox" 
                  Checked="KontoFeltCheckBox_Checked" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: the real question is why would you want to? You can solve this issue with binding. you should never need to(or very rarely) get your ui elements directly

Comment: I agree. Without boring you with the use case, this is in the very rarely category..